# Good reasons NOT to place ViewModels in separate assembly?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm developing a project using the MVVM pattern in WPF.

One of the key benefits to MVVM is maintaining clear separation between business logic and presentation.

As a test to see how well separated everything actually was, over the weekend I spiked moving all ViewModels, Models, and business logic to a separate .dll. The .exe was left as a thin presentation layer.

This worked, seamlessly, *first try*.

I've already seen benefits to keeping views (xaml, presentation) in the .exe and core logic in its own dll. For example, there's no longer [any](http://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+mvvm+no+code+behind) [dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wpf+mvvm+code+behind) in my mind about whether code-behind in Xaml is an issue: I'm comfortable with it if it becomes necessary, since I know it's presentation specific.

So far this exe/dll separation has worked so well that my question is: Has anyone experienced any **downside** to this approach?

Related question: [Implementing MVVM in WPF without using System.Windows.Input.ICommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503329/implementing-mvvm-in-wpf-without-using-system-windows-input-icommand)

Comment: Why would the split not have worked? It's the same code and so long as the access levels is correct there should be no problem. A better test of your VM layer is can you attach a different UI to it, like Silverlight, or even run your app entirely from a unit test.

Comment: "Why would the split not have worked" - that's exactly my question. Are there any technical gotchas here ?

Comment: What is the pro of doing this? It seems unneccessary unless you literally need to use the model in another project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 weeks now with my Model & View Models in a dll, my xaml in an exe and no problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 7):

We use this kind of separation in all of our products because it helps us to see if any code violates against the UI - business logic separation.

Most times we do it the same way as you have suggested:

- Sample.Presentation.exe (Contains all the WPF stuff, thin assembly)
- Sample.Applications.dll (Is responsible to the application's workflow, here are all ViewModels)
- Sample.Domain.dll (Here are the business rules)

We don't have encountered any issues yet and I don't expect to see any problems in future.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any spcific issues with this approach besides the general pro/con for using few/many projects.

Answer (score 1):

The actual question is ... what are assembles for?

They are a way to separate logic making it unavailable to other code unless you add a reference, so in fact they are a way of hiding parts of code from other parts.

Given this purpose and the way you are using it I would say that you're doing it right.

Having said that I find much easier to verify that the Views do not have any code behind in code reviews and keep the views in the same assembly. Less projects = faster compile and load times.